# Difference in length of two dimensional concentric closed paths

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves

Two bicyclists ride side by side around a smooth loop with the outside bicyclist a distance of $D$ from the inside bicyclist.
How much further does the outside bicyclist ride?
If the loop is a circle, the answer is $2 \pi D$.
My conjecture is that the answer is the same for all smooth convex loops.

Comment: A smooth loop where. Inside the plane? Inside some surface in the Euclidean 3-space? Inside an arbitrary Euclidean 3-space? [The answer is hidden in the title but should be explicit in the body.] How do you define "the outside ride" for an arbitrary loop? Maybe assume convexity from the beginning.

Comment: I used bicyclists in the description of the problem to imply the ordinary Euclidean plane.  One does not need convex loops for the statement to be true but I didn't know how to pose it simply for just a smooth closed path that doesn't cross itself.  I'm just a poor electrical engineer.

Comment: For a simple [=no self-intersection] planar path, indeed "exterior" makes sense (but not "concentric").

Answer (score 9):

if you mean that the outer bicyclist's position $f(t)$ is related to the inner bicyclist's position $\gamma(t)$ (where $\gamma$ is a natural parametrization) by $f(t)-\gamma(t)=Dn(t)$, where $n$ is an outer normal to $\gamma$ at $\gamma(t)$, then $\dot{f}$ and $\dot \gamma$ are collinear vectors and by [Frenet-Serret formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) you get $\dot{f}(t)=\dot{\gamma}(t)(1+D\kappa(t))$, where $\kappa$ is a curvature of $\gamma$ at point $t$. If you assume that $\kappa(t)\geqslant -1/D$ for all $t$, you may comclude that $|\dot{f}(t)|-|\dot{\gamma}(t)|=D\kappa(t)$, and integrating you get indeed $2\pi D$. Without this assumption, no.

Comment: @ChristianRemling sorry, the link is for space curves, when $\kappa$ has fixed sign by definition.

Answer (score 4):

It the plane convex curve in $\mathbb R^2$ is closed smooth continuous , we  have a common normal for inner and outer parallel tracks during any infinitesimal rotation of the normal.

Reckoning arc distance from an arbitrary point of the inner track/curve

[image]

$$ ds_1= \rho d \varphi,~ ds_2= (\rho+D) d \varphi ;~$$

we calculate for the entire closed non-interesting (Jordan) oval the difference between two perimeters

$$ \int (ds_2-ds_1)= \int_0^{2\pi} D~d\varphi = 2 \pi D. $$

Point $O$ can be considered to be on the evolute of the oval.

So the conjecture is correct.

Comment: I think this is kind of argument used somewhere in complex analysis. Cauchy, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

The question is related to Steiner's formula. Here $A(E)$ stands for the area of $E$.

> **Theorem 1.** If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded $C^2$ domain, and $$\Omega_r=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: d(x,\Omega)\leq r\},$$ then there is $r_0>0$ such
> that  $$ \operatorname{A}(\Omega_r)=
> \operatorname{A}(\Omega)+L(\partial\Omega)r+\pi r^2\chi(\Omega), 
> \quad \text{for $0\leq r\leq r_0$},$$  where $\chi(\Omega)$ is the
> Euler characteristic of $\Omega$. In particular if $\partial\Omega$ is a closed Jordan curve, $\chi(\Omega)=1$, and we have
> $$
> \operatorname{A}(\Omega_r)=
> \operatorname{A}(\Omega)+L(\partial\Omega)r+\pi r^2, 
> \quad \text{for $0\leq r\leq r_0$}
> $$

> **Theorem 2.** If $\Omega$ is bounded and convex, then $$ \operatorname{A}(\Omega_r)= 
>  \operatorname{A}(\Omega)+L(\partial\Omega)r+\pi r^2,   \quad \text{for
>  all $r>0$.} $$

You can find a detailed proofs and references here https://mathoverflow.net/a/303042/121665.

Now the length of the curve at the distance $r$ to $\Omega$ is the derivative of $A(\Omega_r)$ with respect to $r$ and hence for $r\leq r_0$ it equals $L(\partial\Omega)+2\pi r\chi_\Omega$ and $L(\partial\Omega)+2\pi r$ in the case of the Jordan curve. If $\Omega$ is any bounded convex set  with non-empty interior (need not be smooth), then it equals $L(\partial\Omega)+2\pi r$ for all $r\geq 0$.